# Add Timestamp USB barcode scanner

Tags: scanner, barcode

I bought a U[SB Honeywell 5145](http://www.barcodewinkel.nl/product/honeywell-eclipse-5145-usb-kit-zwart-mk5145-31a38-eu/) barcode scanner

And want to add for each scan system- time and date. I searching for a way to connect with the USB port for data tweaking. Tried Gnome terminal but that does not did the trick so far.